# StreamCorruptedException at ObjectOutputStream::writeObject

Tags: java, android, sockets

The below is my class. It simple write a serialized object to socket output stream. I got a strange error at writeObject line. Why?

```
W/System.err(  576): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
W/System.err(  576):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1712)
W/System.err(  576):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1665)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.megaclient.activity.ControlActivity.sendDelta(ControlActivity.java:92)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.megaclient.activity.ControlActivity.touchTouchPad(ControlActivity.java:68)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.megaclient.activity.ControlActivity.access$0(ControlActivity.java:48)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.megaclient.activity.ControlActivity$1.onTouch(ControlActivity.java:42)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(  576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
W/System.err(  576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(  576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err(  576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/System.err(  576):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My class

```
public class ControlActivity extends Activity {
...

    public void somewhere() {
    ...
                    final Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                    sendDelta(socket, dx, dy);
    ....
    }

    public void sendDelta(final Socket socket, final int dx, final int dy) {
        try {
            final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            final MegaPoint point = new MegaPoint(dx, dy);
            oos.writeObject(point);

            oos.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (final StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public class MegaPoint implements Serializable {

    private final int x, y;

    public MegaPoint(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
```

Comment: What does the rest of your stack trace look like?

Comment: You can copy the log using a normal terminal, run `adb logcat` (given adb is in your path. If it is not, use `cd /path/to/your/androidsdk/platform-tools` followed by `./adb logcat`)